# Errno 22 Invalid argument: 'F:\\Python\\Library\\resources\\icudtl.dat'

Tags: python-3.x

```
(base) F:\>conda install -c anaconda nltk
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.6.11
  latest version: 4.6.14
Please update conda by running
    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
## Package Plan ##
  environment location: F:\Python
  added / updated specs:
    - nltk
......................................................
......................................................
Executing transaction: \ WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(138): Could not remove or rename F:\Python\Library\resources\icudtl.dat.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(568): An error occurred while installing package 'anaconda::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'.
OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')
Attempting to roll back.
Rolling back transaction: done
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'F:\\Python\\Library\\resources\\icudtl.dat'enter link description here
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 9):

Close all instances of Python in your machine and then try to run the install. I got the same error while installing keras. I tried to remove the .dat file manually, but it said the file was in use in Python. So, I closed Spyder and reran the install, it worked. I use Python3.7

Comment: This worked for me! Remember, that conda will create a new file with the same name in the same directory, during the installation. Do not delete the new file during the installation!